# Wordpress - Active class on raw html menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress to create a website and I have a special menu used on mobile only. Like this :

```
<a class="mobile-menu" href="#"><h1>Artists</h1></a>
<a class="mobile-menu" href="#"><h1>Exhibitions</h1></a>
<a class="mobile-menu" href="#"><h1>Gallery</h1></a>
```

I would like to add an active class to underline the active menu item.

Do someone have an idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have created a custom theme and are using a custom template.  In the template code for your page you could get the page id or page slug then in php echo "active" or whatever in the class portion.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;

    function echoActiveIfSlugIs($pageString = ""){
        global $post_slug;
        if ($post_slug === $pageString){
            echo " active-class-here ";
        }
    }
?>
<a class="mobile-menu <?php echoActiveIfSlugIs('artists'); ?> " href="#"><h1>Artists</h1></a>
<a class="mobile-menu <?php echoActiveIfSlugIs('exhibitions'); ?>" href="#"><h1>Exhibitions</h1></a>
<a class="mobile-menu <?php echoActiveIfSlugIs('gallery'); ?>" href="#"><h1>Gallery</h1></a>
```

You can do the same sort of logic by checking page ID but slugs are usually easier to work with.

Comment: That's not working. If I inspect the element i have this class on my menu of my page artists : mobile-menu <?php echoActiveIfSlugIs('artists'); ?>

Comment: @AntoineKurka This code needs to be added to a template file.  So like on sidebar.php or maybe in your header.php depending on where you have the mobile menu.  If the php tags are showing up in inspect element it means you didn't put the code in a php file but instead probably put it in through wordpress.